# Failed to create provisioning profile - where can I free bundle identifier?

Tags: ios, xcode

I've created project and set some bundle identifier to it. That time I've set up my personal team to the project. Now I need to use new developer account for the project, but Xcode can't create provisioning profile and I cannot find where I can free bundle identifier so I could use it with this account. Any thoughts on it?

Comment: edit to make a more specific question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BundleIDs are never 'released' (only transferred between paid accounts). Once on record, they stay with that record. So, you'll have to create a new bundle id (maybe just a one character modification) and use that with your new account.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote. Can you also mark it as answered? (click the checkmark under this post, on the left. I think it's right below the arrows). https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Yes, sure. I've just forgot to do that right after the answer.